# The difference between $ and $$ in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I was wondering what is the difference between `$` and `$$` in MongoDB.

For example:

```
    '$sum': {
        '$map': {
            'input': '$data',
            'as': 'currentData',
            'in': { '$size': '$$currentData.d' }
        }
    }
```

What if I will use `$` instead of `$$` in `$$currentData.d`.

Comment: (for future visitors) read this: https://www.practical-mongodb-aggregations.com/guides/expressions.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`$` is referred to the root document fields where as `$$` referred to the variable names.

```
{
  "$sum": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$data",
      "as": "currentData",
      "in": { "$size": "$$currentData.d" }
    }
  }
}
```

Here `'$data'` is the document array field and the `$$currentData` is the variable taken in the `as` expression of `$map` aggregation.